# Poisson Solver using Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, solver, poisson

I am looking for some help with a Poisson Solver I am writing in Mathematica.  The code is quite long with Arrays plugged in, but the full details can be found at http://pastebin.com/uSrSDcW6

I am calculating voltages given charge densities using the central difference method derived from Poisson's Eqn.  After calculating the voltage, I test the data set for convergence.  I am setting convergence thresholds on the order of 10^-1000+.  I have the loop set up to kick out after 10000 iterations incase something goes awry, as a fail safe.  I have a loop counter in place for sanity.  The program seems to run fine as long as the convergence threshold is set to 10^-100.

My question is this:  No matter what I update the threshold too, ex, 10^-100, 10^-150, the computation stops after 633 iterations and kicks out of the loop.  I would appreciate any help with this, I am completely stuck.  I've added comments to the program that should be explanatory for anyone on this forum.  Again, I know this description is limited, so please see the attached url http://pastebin.com/uSrSDcW6 for the full program.

***Update***10/9/12****I've isolated my issue down to the 16 digit machine precision. I need to open that up to my machine max precision of 10^309. Mathematica Help is sparse on how to do this. ex "N[MachinePrecision, 50]". Where would I set this in my program to apply it to all computation? Ill paste the loop here if that helps

Vnew / Vold / RHO are 10x10x34 Matrices
Epsilon is a constant
(*Initialize ConvergenceLoop to O - This will serve as a fail safe to kick out of the loop if necessary*)

ConvergenceLoop = 0;

(*Initialize Convergence to zero*)

Convergence = 0;

While[Convergence == 0  && ConvergenceLoop < 10000,

(*Run through all i,j,k elements,calculating new voltage values*)

Do[Vnew[[i]][[j]][[k]] = (1/(2/deltaX^2 + 2/deltaY^2 + 
        2/deltaZ^2)) *(((Vold[[i + 1]][[j]][[k]] +

```
 Vold[[i - 1]][[j]][[k]])/(deltaX^2)) + ((Vold[[i]][[j + 1]][[k]] + 

  Vold[[i]][[j - 1]][[k]])/(deltaY^2)) + ((Vold[[i]][[j]][[k + 1]] + 

   Vold[[i]][[j]][[k - 1]])/(deltaZ^2)) + ((Rho[[i]][[j]][[k]]/Epsilon))), {i, 2, 9}, {j, 2,9}, {k, 2, 33}];
```

(*Assume converged so the loop is triggered when the test hits the first value exceeding the defined convergence threshold*)

Convergence = 1;

(*This is the convergence test.  User defined Convergence threshold*)

```
 Do[If[Vold[[i]][[j]][[k]] == 0, Null, 

    If[(Vnew[[i]][[j]][[k]] - Vold[[i]][[j]][[k]])/Vold[[i]][[j]][[k]] > .0000001,               Convergence = 0;

(*This is purely diagnostic. I added a Tracker point to follow the convergence along.
```

user defined at any element*)

```
If[i == 5 && j == 5 && k == 10, 

 Print[ "Tracker Point" (Vnew[[i]][[j]][[k]] - 
      Vold[[i]][[j]][[k]])/Vold[[i]][[j]][[k]]], Null],Null]], {i, 2, 9}, {j, 2, 9}, {k, 2, 33}];
```

(*Ignore the first iteration until Vnew and Vold are nonzero*)

If[ConvergenceLoop < 2, Convergence = 0, Null];

(*Forces Vold to evolve with Vnew*)

Vold = Vnew;

ConvergenceLoop ++;]

(*Added SessionTime for future planning purposes*)

If[ConvergenceLoop == 10000,

Print["Convergence Loop Limit Reached. " (SessionTime[]/3600) ],

Print["Convergence Loop Limit Not Reached."]];

(*We broke out of the while loop,meaning our data converged,so print the converged values*)

If[Convergence == 1,

Print[ ConvergenceLoop "Congratulations Converged!"  MatrixForm [Vnew]], Print["Did Not Converge!"]];

Comment: I'm in no mood to dig through your code, but perhaps you need to use arbitrary-precision, and you are using machine precision?  This could be the case if you are comparing two numbers which should be different, but are not due to round-off error.

Comment: Understood - I've isolated my issue down to the 16 digit machine precision.  I need to open that up to my machine max precision of 10^309.  Mathematica Help is sparse on how to do this. ex "N[MachinePrecision, 50]".  Where would I set this in my program to apply it to all computation?

Answer (score 0):

Since based on the comments above you have narrowed this to a precision problem as I suspected, please read these:

[Funny behaviour when plotting a polynomial of high degree and large coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3152/121)

[Global precision setting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6421/121)

[Confused by (apparent) inconsistent precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10624/121)